# Can People See Other Folders in My Dropbox When I share a Certain Folder

Tags: dropbox

I want to share a link to one of the folders(my trial account on Dropbox), say:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cyvefdw2z32x3t6/AAC2nc6QIa-DmRSEpiTKFgppa?dl=0

And I'm wondering if people can see other folders. I couldn't find a way using Dropbox navigation or shortening the URL whether I'm signed into another Dropbox account or not signed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The people with whom share that folder will only see the files and sub folders within it. They will not will not see its parent folder or any other folders in your Dropbox.